# How can I fetch the same URL with different query string with Perl's LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, url, methods, lwp-useragent

I looked up articles about using LWP however I am still lost! On this site we find a list of many schools; see the [overview-page](http://www-db.sn.schule.de/index.php?id=25) and follow some of the links and get some result pages:

I want to parse the sites using LWP::UserAgent and for the parsing : want to use either HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath or HTML::TokeParser

At the moment I am musing bout choosing the right get-request!
I have some issues with the LWP::Useragent. The subsite of the overview can be reached via direct links. but -note: each site has content. e.g. the following URLs of the above mentioned result-pages.

As a Novice here I cannot show you the endings of the different endings by posting the full URL but here you can see the endings:

```
id=21&extern_eid=709
id=21&extern_eid=789
id=21&extern_eid=1297
id=21&extern_eid=761
```

There are many different URLS that differ in the end of the URL. The question is : how to i run LWP::UserAgent? I want fetch and parse & ** all the - 1000 sites.**

Question; Does LWP do the job automatically!? Or do i have to set up LWP :: UserAgent that it will look up the different URLS automatically...

Solutions: Perhaps we have to count up form zero to 10000 with there

extern_eid=709 -(count from zero to 100000) here

www-db.sn.schule.de/index.php?id=21&extern_eid=709

BTW: Here the data for LWP User Agent;

> REQUEST METHODS  The methods described
>   in this section are used to dispatch
>   requests via the user agent. The
>   following request methods are
>   provided:
>
> $ua->get( $url ) $ua->get( $url ,
>   $field_name => $value, ... )
>
> This method will dispatch a GET
>   request on the given $url. Further
>   arguments can be given to initialize
>   the headers of the request. These are
>   given as separate name/value pairs.
>   The return value is a response object.
>   See HTTP::Response for a description
>   of the interface it provides. There
>   will still be a response object
>   returned when LWP can't connect to the
>   server specified in the URL or when
>   other failures in protocol handlers
>   occur.

The question is: How to use LWP::UserAgent on the above mentioned site the right way - effectively!?

I look forward to any and all help!

Comment: how come this question is tagged as PHP? It looks like it's a Perl question...

Comment: Hello Alvin - many thanks for the mail. Sure thing. It is a true Perl-Question. I was way too tired and typed the wrong tag! Now i have corrected it! Again - thx for answering! Merci bien ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to use LWP::UserAgent on same URLs with different query arguments, and you are wondering if LWP::UserAgent provides a way for you to loop through the query arguments?

I don't think LWP::UserAgent has a method for you to do that. However, you can have a loop constructing the URLs and use LWP::UserAgent repeatedly:

```
for my $id (0 .. 100000)
{
    $ua->get($url."?id=21&extern_eid=".(709-$id))
    //rest of the code
}
```

Alternatively you can add a request_prepare handler that computes and add the query arguments before you send out the request.

Comment: Many thanks Alvin! or - i better to do that: 


for my $i (0..10000) {
  $ua->get('http://www-db.sn.schule.de/index.php', id => 21, extern_uid => $i);
  # process reply
}  
In any case, using a loop like this for that kind of job is a  way to do it. I guess the LWP APIs does not aim to replace the functionality of the core Perl, and we can use Perl loops to query multiple URLs. If i create a loop - i have some that do not match results: what do i do in the subseqently parsing process. I will have a check!? i have to do a check to get rid of all those results that do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You describe following links for the purpose of web scraping. The LWP subclass [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) does this more easily than your current attempt.